# Meteor.js 1.0 - Data context involving Iron Router and template helpers

Tags: meteor, coffeescript

I'm using Iron Router to pass data through to my templates:

```
@route 'singleProperty',
  path: '/properties/:_id'
  data: ->
    Properties.findOne(@params._id)
  controller: "SinglePropertyController"
```

And within my controller, I have my template waiting for the necessary collection to be published:

```
waitOn: ->
  [
    Meteor.subscribe "properties"
  ]
```

The issue that I am having is that when I try to access `@data` from within my helpers, it comes back as `undefined`:

```
Template.singleProperty.helpers
  currentProperty: ->
    console.log @data
```

That said, when I run the same `console.log` within a `Template.rendered`, I get the result that I would expect (the `data` object):

```
Template.singleProperty.rendered = ->
  console.log @data
```

What do I need to change to be able to access `data` within a `Template.helper`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your Template helper method:
**Template.currentData()**

**Template.instance()** is the key thing to read upon in the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_inst)

hope this helps.

Comment: Template.currentData() did the trick. If only I had read about that 3 hours ago!

Comment: Glad to see it helped...sometimes we are simply not seeing the wood for the trees...